# Google Oauth2 Playground blocked - how can I unblock it?

Tags: google-oauth, oauth2-playground, google-playground

I was trying to assume roles in order to test the CloudSearch API, and I'm locked out.

I see:

```
This app is blocked
The app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked access.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the id of the playground, so I followed [this guide](https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F7281227) with this id: 407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com.

Comment: Hats off!! I was getting pissed at Google not providing straightforward documentation.

Comment: How can I get this working if my account is not a Google Workspace admin account?

Answer (score 0):

This procedure on the google admin panel helps you out:

https://support.claralabs.com/article/132-how-do-i-fix-this-app-is-blocked-error-message-when-authorizing-clara-app-to-access-my-calendar

You just need to add `playground` as an allowed third-party app according to the above instruction.